# Search for words with a Dash in Twitter API

Tags: search, twitter

How can I get the results for the phrase "E-Contact" In a normal twitter search it returns results with E-Contact but also results without the dash [anything but](http://twitter.com/#!/search/e-contact)

The same happens for a [Williams-Sonoma search](http://twitter.com/#!/search/williams-sonoma) I tried using quotes and also replacing the dash with the URL encoded %2D but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. You will have to manually filter the search results on your side.